Simple roots.io WordPress site that doesn't work when pulled down form bitbucket repo - Uncaught Error: Class 'Roots\WPConfig\Config' not found
I've setup a simple roots.io bedrock site and tested it in my local browser through MAMP.
My problem is when I push this site to a bitbucket repo, and then pull it down again the site doesn't work.
I have a repo setup through bitbucket and I have done a commit and push on everything, no files are set to ignore.
I delete everything off my local machine, pull down the repo, navigate to the folder and run composer install.
I then try and load the site and I get a 500 error, and in my php log I see the following error. -
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Roots\WPConfig\Config' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/es-street-new/config/application.php:54
I look in my files and I can see that there is a missing config.php in Roots\WPConfig\
Putting the missing file in here from a local roots.io bedrock site doesn't fix the problem.
Has anybody else ever run into this problem?
Thanks in advance for any help :)
